# How to translate a joint configuration

Tags: path-planning, joint, rrt

I'm currently working on a basic implementation of the RRT algorithm to control my 6DOF robotic arm.
But how can I reduce the node to be in the radius of the nearest node of my graph without using the inverse kinematic ? If I use the IK, I'm losing all the informations I had with the joints.

So what is the way to do a "translation" of a joint configuration to have a new one which is in the radius of another joint configuration ?

Comment: By radius of another configuration, do you mean the distance between the forward kinematics of the original configuration and the new configuration - or the configuration space distance?

Comment: If I correctly understood how it works, I'm talking about the configuration space distance. Currently, what I'm doing is comparing the forward kinematics points, but to keep using joints I have to do an inverse kinematic afterward. So I suppose I should always stay in the configuration space.